# Get the number of objects in the image from the edges drawn

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect the number of blobs for example placed on a surface. What i have tried so far:

1. Converted image to grayscale
2. Applied threshold to the image
   3, Obtained the edges
3. Drawn the edges using the mat (the image below)

[image]

I am using opencv for android in my case, and i need help in order to find the number of objects in the image. Could anyone please help me. I  have tried filling the image using the code below but it doesnot help

```
for(int ii=0;ii<dst.rows();ii++) {
        for(int j=0;j<dst.cols();j++) {
            double checker = dst.get(ii, j)[0];          
            if(checker == 255) {
                Imgproc.floodFill(dst, matMask, 
                       new Point(j,ii), new Scalar(255), 
                       null,new Scalar(255), new Scalar(255), 8);
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
The captured image on which processing has to be done:

the background might look like this
[image: the background might look like this]!

Or another possibility
[image: Or another possibility]

Thanking you

Comment: if the number of objects in your sample image is `2` (you didnt define `object`) you can use `findContours` with the parameter only extracting "outer contours". number of found contours equals the number of objects if not overlapping.

Comment: @Micka - thank you for the hint i will look into findCountours and how to get only the outer countours.. and currently yes i am only focusing on one kind of an object but then once this is cleared, i wish to combine multiple objects, in that case, how do i just define ellipsed type of objects ? could you assist please?

Comment: Have a look at RANSAC circle/line detection. This can easily reformulated to detect ellipses

Comment: this is in opencv ? i will google more on it..

Comment: @Micka - positive results.. i managed to get a count of elipses.. i mean filled it with fitellipse and then the count.. will this work for circles too ?? incase i mix a circle with an elipse?

Comment: I dont know whether there is a RANSAC  ellipse fitting un openCV. But you can detect any circle with ellipse fitting since circle is special case of ellipse

Comment: @Micka - yes it works, but then in the elipse method, even small particles are counted :( which is not what i want. I am trying to count a capsule do i have to consider area also in this case ? I have no clue what area a capsule holds though

Comment: hard to tell. If you can choose a proper heuristic about size you can use a cv function to calculate the area of a contour. afair it is calles `contourArea`, but I'm not sure. If you cant choose such a heuristic since you dont know boundaries of your objects size, you'll have to distinguish with other criteria.

Comment: I have just edited my question, with the image on which processing has to be done. @Micka